# Define path exclusions for find globally

Tags: find

I have 2 directories that I want to exclude from all my **find** searches: **.git** and **node_modules**

I've been trying to define an alias that would do it, but haven't been successful.

Something similar to GREP_OPTIONS would be ideal, but alas.

Comment: To clarify, you want to exclude any results from any folder than has either a `.git` or `node_modules` in the path? Which operating system, and shell if applicable, are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual... it takes me reaching out for help to solve the problem myself...

```
alias find='find . ! -path "*/.git/*" ! -path "*/node_modules/*"'
```